# Ormlite android не записывается значение

Tags: java, android, sqlite, orm

Здравствуйте. У меня есть ормлайт база, в ней есть булеан поле, нужно в коде заменить его на противоположное. Изначально значение записывается, но после смены ориентации не сохраняется.

база:

```
@DatabaseField
@JsonProperty
private Boolean side;
 public boolean getSide() {
    return side;
}

public void setSide(boolean side) {
    this.side = side;
}
замена значения:

final boolean isFrontSide = app.getSide();
app.setSide(!isFrontSide);
```

Comment: @Сергей Ц, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае вы путаете присваивание значения переменной объекта и изменение значения записи в БД.

Можно сделать по разному, например так:

Создаём метод в классе-таблице, который будет принимать в себя DAO таблицы, ID записи и значение типа boolean, находить по ID запись и менять значение нужной колонки:

```
public static void updateBoolean(YoursDaoObject dao, int id, boolean value)
{
    UpdateBuilder<YoursTableClass, Integer> updateBuilder;
    try
    {
        updateBuilder = dao.updateBuilder();
        updateBuilder.where().eq("nameOfYoursIDField", id);
        updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("nameOfYoursBooleanField", value);
        updateBuilder.update();
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[[@ЮрийСПб](/users/17609/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B1)](/users/17609/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B1), я думаю, что ты путаешь ORM с чем-то не ORM. =)

[[@Сергей Ц](/users/26802/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%86)](/users/26802/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%86), хороший вариант спросить на гите проекта, а еще лучше посмотреть доки, хотя бы sqlite, и разобраться, умеет ли она хранить boolean, умеет ли хранить его ORM, и если нет - хранить 0/1 и конвертить.

Comment: @Gorets, не... Тут же в вопросе прямо написано, что пользуется OrmLite либа, кою я тоже (вот прямо сейчас) пользую. И я точно понял суть проблемы и точно правильно ответил)

Боюсь, что вопроса не поняли именно вы...